# Javafx gridpane row index not adding to the right place

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a Gridpane of 64x64 tiles. The gridpane setup is

```
public class ButtonPanel extends GridPane {

    public ButtonPanel(Node parent) {
        ButtonPanel.setFillHeight(parent, true);
        this.setPrefSize(264,720);
        this.setPadding(new Insets(8));
        this.setVgap(64);
          setGridLinesVisible(true);
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F1F5F8; -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 10, 0, 0, 0);");
    }
}
```

and I add buttons like so:

```
buttonPanelMain.add(new Button(), 0, 0);
buttonPanelMain.add(new Button(), 0, 1);
```

which in idea, would have both buttons at column 0 in the first and secod row. What I get however, is this

[image]

As you can see, one row is being left between... How to solve this?

Comment: By not setting `vgap` to something other than `0`? The second button ***is*** in the second row. You're only instructing your `GridPane` to leave a empty space of `64` between rows...

Comment: @fabian Please, make this an answer :)